# How to return data from Tanstack React Query useMutation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have a form, and I want to return the id from the newly created object which I'm creating through Axios via a REST API.

I'm integrating Tanstack Query, using the useMutation hook. I've created my own hook so I can use the mutation code throughout my react application.

```
const useCreateUser = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({ user, accessToken }: createUserInputs) =>
      createUser(user, accessToken),
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    },
  });
};
```

Console.log(data) is working.

I'm declaring the hook like this:

```
const { data:createduser, mutate: createUser } = useCreateUser();
```

and calling the hook like this:

```
await createUser({ user: user, accessToken: accessToken });
```

but this is not returning the data.

Where am I going wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get returning data from data useMutations props:

```
const { data:createduser, mutate: createUser,  isSuccess } = useCreateUser();


createUser({ user: user, accessToken: accessToken });
if(isSuccess){
console.log(createduser) // data here!
}
```

Comment: thank you, the issue was the await in "await createUser({ user: user, accessToken: accessToken });"

Answer (score 5):

You can use mutateAsync instead of mutate. mutateAsync will return the value.